# Float as percent rounding

Tags: c#

I want to output a float representing a percentage as follows :

```
float fPct = 0.995f;   // I want 000099% as output.
```

Now a use :

```
string str = fPct.ToString("000000%");  // But this gives me 000100%.
```

How can I prevent the rounding ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `float` instead of `double` or `decimal`?

Comment: Don't need full precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Math.Truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx) to get rid of the fractional part, but you'll have to do the conversion to percent yourself:

```
float fPct = 0.995f;
string str = Math.Truncate(fPct * 100).ToString("000000") + "%"; // 000099%
// or
string str = $"{Math.Truncate(fPct * 100):000000}%"; // 000099%
```

Note that this would have the same effect as simply converting to an `int`:

```
float fPct = 0.995f;
string str = $"{(int)(fPct * 100):000000}%"; // 000099%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

`(0.995f * 100).ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "%"`

this will produce `"000099.5%"`

Not sure if you need discard `5`, though.

You multiply by `100` cause you're about to present a *percent*, but you have a *ratio*.